# What is $f$ if $f(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ and $\frac{f(x)}{x}\to\frac{1}{2}$ as $x\to 0$?

Tags: calculus

I was asked this question in a test:

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a function such that $f(x)=\int\limits_0^x f(t)\,dt$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{2}$. What is $f(\ln 3)$?

If $f$ is integrable then $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ is continuous, which in turn means $f$ is continuous. By fundamental theorem of calculus this also means $f$ is differentiable. So from $f'=f$, I end up with the familiar result that $f$ is identically zero. But with the additional condition $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{2}$, this is not true. I am not sure how this condition changes the answer. Is it possible for a function $f$ to be satisfying both conditions in the question? Any hint would be great.

Comment: There is no such function. $f'=f$ says  $f(t)=ce^t$; if $c\ne0$ then $\lim_{x\to0}|f(x)/x|=\infty$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: Alternatively, in addition to $f'(x) = f(x)$ you get from the integral equation the initial condition that $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zero function $f(x) = 0$ is not the only solution to the differential equation $f'(x) = f(x)$.  Note $$f(x) = Ce^x$$ is a family of solutions satisfying this property.  Then you wish to find a value of $C$ such that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{Ce^x}{x} = \frac{1}{2}.$$  But no such $C$ exists since $e^0 = 1$.

Comment: I wonder why I spend so much time with wrong questions.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Sometimes, you can learn more from a wrongly posed question than a properly posed one.  For example, in what ways could you change the limit criterion so that the question has a well-defined answer?  One possibility is to change it to $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \frac{1}{2}.$$  Then what is the answer?  Can you think of another change that would work?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. We have $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)=f(0)=0$. This was a multiple choice question with none of the answers being 'zero'.